# Java: NoSuchElementException when reading console

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I've already made some researchs, but i found nothing.

So here is my code:

```
public void play(){
    System.out.print("Make your choice ( R - P - S) : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
    setChoice(choice);
    sc.close();
}
```

The first time I enter this function, everything is ok, but the next times, it throws  `NoSuchElementException` on the 3rd line of my function.
Another thing: when I delete `sc.close()` line, the problem desappears, but I want to keep that line.

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you close a `Scanner`, it will also close underlying input stream, that is, `System.in`. So you couldn't close it.

Answer (score 0):

dont close Scanner it is the problem here.it will close underlying input stream

```
sc.close();
```

Comment: Ok thanks guys. So I delete sc.close() line, but I still have the warning `Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed`. What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

[`Scanner.close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29)

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying
>   readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's
>   close method will be invoked. If this scanner is already closed then
>   invoking this method will have no effect.

`System.in` is an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) which implements [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

This implies that calling `close()` on `sc` invokes `close()` method of `System.in`, which closes the input stream and releases any system resources associated with it.